# Trouble in creating Trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database with some tables. I want to create a trigger to 'Delete a record in tblplayersfield with "pID" of the record which was deleted in tblplayers'

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_from AFTER DELETE on tblplayers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tblplayerfields
    WHERE 'tblplayerfields'.'pID' = OLD.'pID';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a delimiter change first

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER delete_from AFTER DELETE on tblplayers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tblplayerfields
    WHERE 'tblplayerfields'.'pID' = OLD.'pID';
END
|
delimiter ;
```

The delimiter signals the DB engine the end of your statement. Normally it is `;`. But that would end the stored procedure at the first `;`. And its definition would be incomplete.

You can change the delimiter and add it to the end of your procedure. After that change the delimiter back to `;`